# How to prove linear independence in S, the vector space of signals?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Suppose that f, g, and h are linearly independent functions defined for all real numbers, and suppose that we construct three signals by sampling their values at integers: $$u_k = f(k), v_k = g(k), w_k = h(k)$$ Is it necessarily the case that the signals are linearly independent in S, the vector space of signals? How do we prove/disprove this?

I'm thinking that I would have to start this problem with plugging in $$u_k, v_k, w_k$$ into a Casorati matrix and solve for the determinant of C(0) to see if those signals are linearly independent, but I'm not sure how to do so with the fact that each signal is a function itself. Any help would be truly appreciated!

Comment: As soon as you brought determinants into this, your approach became more complicated than it need to be. You should find this question much easier to answer (by constructing a suitable counterexample) if you first answer the questions posed in this [answer to your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3897124/81360).

Comment: Understood! I'll stay away from determinants, but I'm assuming that I should still use a Casorati matrix? @BenGrossmann

Comment: Not what I had in mind. Think about the linked question, "from scratch".