# Is this function one-to-one? Is it onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, proof-writing, linear-transformations, solution-verification

The map $$T:V(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow S$$ from the vector space of real-valued functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$ to the space of ssignals defined by sending each function to the signal obtained by evaluating at integers is linear (i.e. $T(f_ = {u_k}$) where $u_k = f(k)$).

Is it one-to-one? Is it onto?

I'm honestly not really sure where to start with this proof. I'm guessing that in order to prove that the mapping is onto/one-to-one, we'll have to manipulate T. I also know that functions in $V(\mathbb{R})$ are just arbitrary functions f: $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it one-to-one?

Can you find two different functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(k)=g(k)$ for all integers?

> Is it onto?

If you have some sequence of real numbers $(u_k)_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$, can you find a function $f$ such that $f(k) = u_k$ for all $k$?